# Excel, show Subtotals distributed according to various conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to do the following:

I have a column "volume" that looks like the column on the pic.

This VOLUME ROW is flexible meaning that it can be shorter or larger depending on the situation. Its not fixed and volume changes constantly.

I would like to make subtotals:

1. Minimum amount is 800. The sum of minimum 800 should be diplayed. It can´t be 799, it 
   has to be equal or above 800. In this case 818 is the correct sum! It has to reach minimum 800 and max. 2000, but must not exceed 2000.
2. Maximum amount is 2000. Since 2000 is the limit, it must not exceed 2000. Therefore the correct sum to 
   display is the nearest amount below 2000 or equal to 2000. In this case 1940 is the correct sum!
3. After 2000 or in this case 1940 is reached it starts to count from cero 
   until it reraches again minimum 800 to max. 2000. 
   And so on until the end of volume column

Here is a picture to better understand what it should look like.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't help but think of the [Holy Hand Grenade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk) reading the description.  That being said, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  You could use `MIN()` and `MAX()` to set the sum. Are you trying to go "down" the column until you hit at least `800` but no more than `2000`, and return that sum?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with formulas:

- B2: `=IF(C1+A2>=2000,A2,B1+A2)`
- C2: `=IF(AND(B2>=800,B1<800),B2,IF(B2+A3>=2000,B2,0))`

copy formulas down and make sure B1 and C1 are empty or `0`. Column C then shows either 0 or the lower and higher bond of the sum that you requested. Column B is only a helper column needed to calculate the sums.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the rows in Column A, and keep a running total.

You can then check the running total against your limits, and write the value / update the running total, as needed:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    lRow = 2
    With ActiveSheet
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(lRow, 1))
            If i < 800 Then
                i = i + .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
                If i >= 800 Then .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = i
            Else
                i = i + .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
                If i + .Cells(lRow + 1, 1).Value >= 2000 Then
                    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = i
                    i = 0
                End If
            End If
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```